# Update partial view after submit Ajax.Beginform

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am new at .NET mvc.

In a view "DisplayThings" I have something like:

```
@foreach (var thing in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("DisplayPartial", thing)
}
```

In the partial view "DisplayPartial" I have

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Afunc", new AjaxOptions ()))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AstringThing)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AintThing)

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajax Post" />
}
```

At the moment the "Afunc"-Action saves the model to the database and then redirects to a controller action to retrieve all "things" from the database and render the entire "Displaythings" View.

My question is: When i press one of the submitbuttons (There is one submitbutton for every "thing" i the list). I want only that partial view to reload/reflect on my change. I dont want to reload the entire "Displaythings" view. How do I do this? If I just return a partial view I lose everything else but that partial view.

If this is a bad approach please give me directions.

**Update:**

I am still doing something wrong as I get the partial view rendered in a new page. My controller :

```
public ActionResult Afunc(ThingModel thingmodel)
{
    // do

    return PartialView("DisplayPartial", thingmodel);
}
```

I have tried using UpdateTargetId and onsuccess both with the same result (A new page)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `AjaxOptions` that your are simply now passing as `new AjaxOptions` you can specify the target element using the `UpdateTargetId` property:

```
<div id="unique_thing_id">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Afunc", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = 'unique_thing_id' }))
{    
}
</div>
```

Above, a container with unique id for every "thing" is represented with `<div id="unique_thing_id">`. This will be replaced with the repsonse of the request. Change `Afunc` to render only the particular "thing" partial.

Comment: I will accept you answer since you pointed out something I was missing. THat was however only one of 2 things I had missed. A common issue is to forget(after surfing the net) to add this to your layoutpage: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @manojlds I opened a new question, could you please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868493/form-reload-but-partialview-cannot-with-ajax-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment49779357_30868493)  question?