# Need clarification; Post from partial view with no JS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been searching for an answer to this question for a while now, I was hoping someone could give me clarity:

If I do a post from a partial View (or a called @Html.Action()) then there is no way save for usage of client-side scripting to have the application preserve state?

phrased differently: I can not post from a partial and just have it "do that part" and have the rest of the controllers remain as they were (provided no unsaved forms ofc)? Again with no java-script or the like.

What happens for me is that when I process the Http.Post and return a partial view, then that is the entirety of what gets written to the output pipeline and everything else in the browser vanishes.

I'm "solving" this right now by passing along a return-URL so I can redirect as an actionresult rather than send a partial view at the conclusion of the Http.Post processing. Is this the best I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to update your partial view 
 this Question can be helpful for you
[Update partial view after submit Ajax.Beginform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801322/update-partial-view-after-submit-ajax-beginform)

Comment: Thank you for a good try Ali, but this is (thrice mentioned) without clientside scripting. Also no direct answer to any of my questions.

Comment: why are you not using js the most loved one to remove post backs you should use json to update your partial view without postback

Comment: Well I want to learn how to do it the right way. JS is not always available. In a way you let the UI be responsible for the statefullness of the application, which while working in 99% of cases is hard to consider flawless. (That said, I will use it where appropriate. This time I it was to have a button to go in and out of edit-mode, so all controlls would need to be reloaded anyway).